# Trouble flagging conditions in Excel using VB

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to flag records where a condition is met and am getting 'almost' answers. There is a column with - and + values. The code will iterate until sum = 2000 OR (sum>=2000 and next record is positive) - so the last consecutive negative record that >= 2000 will get flagged.  Code below does not wait until the end of the last negative number (i.e, 30 records in a row with - number). Any thoughts on fixing?

```
 Dim homecell As Range
Set homecell = Range("I1")


Set homecell = Range("A1").EntireRow.Find("2k Flag")
homecell.Select
homecell.EntireColumn.ClearContents
homecell = "2k Flag"

Dim i As Long
i = 1
Dim a As Long
a = 0
Dim pos As Boolean
Dim sum As Double
Dim sfrom As Double
sfrom = 1
i = 1
Dim wforp As Boolean

Do Until sfrom > Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row

If Range("A1").Offset(sfrom, 0) = Range("A1").Offset(sfrom + a, 0) Then

Do Until a = 2000 Or (sum <= -200 And pos = False) Or pos = True
sum = sum + homecell.Offset(sfrom + a, -1)
If homecell.Offset(sfrom + a, -1) > 0 Then
pos = True
wforp = False
End If

a = a + 1
Loop

If pos = False And sum <= -200 And wforp = False Then
homecell.Offset(sfrom + a - 1, 0) = "yes"
wforp = True
sfrom = sfrom + a - 1

End If

sum = 0
pos = False
a = 0

Else
wforp = False

End If

sfrom = sfrom + 1
Loop
```

Comment: Would you post a subset of your data and indicate: which col(s) you are searching and a subset of the same data with your expected results/output

Comment: thank you. here is a sample of the dataset. the script does iterate thru a dataset with unique sub-sets, called by field 'pipeline ID', so the analysis does not bleed over from one pipeline ID to another.   

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/35610819/test.xlsx

Comment: OK thank you.  Hopefully, a final bit of clarification please. How do you know if the code is performing correctly?  For example, in your data example you have 'yes' flags at rows 215, 250 and 317 e.g. should there be more flags and if so where in your code sample; less?  Also what do you mean by "does not wait until the end of the last negative number (i.e. 30 records in a row with - number)" e.g. are you getting a code error , is 30 an absolute value because there is a  run of more than 30 consecutive -ve no's in your data.

Comment: the code will assign 'yes' for record in last column. when script is done I can see the records that are flagged. if negative values meet or exceed -2000, keep going until next record is positive, then flag the last negative record. then start over. if consecutive records of negative numbers reach end but do not meet or exceed -2000 then dont flag. So if 26 consecutive records sum equals -3,450, flag last records in this group. then start over. hope that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the line

`Do Until a = 2000 Or (sumneg <= -200 And pos = False) Or pos = True`

to

```
Do Until a = 2000 Or (sumneg <= -2000 And pos = False) Or pos = True
```

i.e. sumneg <= **-2000**

Note that I have changed your variable 'sum' to 'sumneg' to avoid any confusion with the VBA reserved keyword.

Might be a good idea and give you more flexibility to declare this value as a variable itself.

Wasn't quite sure about flagging the last value in the group but if you do want this then replace

```
sfrom = sfrom + a - 1
```

with the following code:

```
 sfrom = (sfrom + a - 1) + 1

        Do While homecell.Offset(sfrom, -1) < 0

            sfrom = sfrom + 1
        Loop

    homecell.Offset(sfrom - 1, 0) = "last neg in group"
```